# How to do wrap() with a text-selection from getSelectedText()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to warp a div around a selected text, but I don't know how I can do it in the easiest way?
I catch the selected text by,

```
myselection = window.getSelection();
```

For example we have `"123456789"` and I have select `"456"`
I want at the end,

```
"123<div>456</div>789"
```

I know it should be possible with wrap() but normally I use it every time with a selector as kind of class or id. How can I use the `wrap()` function for a selection object?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: you can get the node from `getSelection().anchorNode`. Use the node data to search for string and prepare new element with cloned properties. Then hide the old element and insert the new prepared element in the same place as old element

Comment: it sounds a bit complicate? coud you do me a smal example, i dont now wich thinks from the anchorNode i should use in wich way..?

Comment: no thats not dublicate! here we have to start with a selector-object so i think we should let the questions as it is!

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you can try something like this

```
let selectedString = window.getSelection().toString()
let selectedNode = $(window.getSelection().anchorNode).parent()
let fullText = selectedNode.get(0).innerHTML
let finalText = fullText.replace(selectedString, "<span style='background:red'>" + selectedString + "</span>")
selectedNode.get(0).innerHTML = finalText
```